# MUI v5 - theme.js - specify classes

Tags: css, autocomplete, material-ui

in the console I have this css class:

.MuiAutocomplete-hasPopupIcon.MuiAutocomplete-hasClearIcon.css-10pnirh-MuiAutocomplete-root .MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot

How can I define it in theme.js to override?

[image]